# Hashing sections of a PE file using pefile module

Tags: python-2.7, hash, sections

I have written script in python that uses the pefile module to parse PE files. One of the features of my script is i would like the ability to generate the md5 and sha256 hash for each section contained within a PE file. Looking a the code for the pefile module there is a class called SectionStructure. Within this class there are methods that allow for the return of both the md5 and sha256 hash of the PE section's data. I am not sure how to properly access these methods within my script and I am seeking the advice of more seasoned developers to assist with this. Can someone please point me in the right direction in getting this functionality to work? I will share my script upon request.

Comment: In order to receive some help, you should provide some code along with your answer.

Comment: you can download the script from my git hub: https://github.com/malre-rcs/pescan.git. Please forgive the code. I'm not a developer and this is my first real program.

Comment: or you can add the relevant part in your question.

Comment: I currently don't have code explicitly for that part of my question I because I'm stuck in general on how to access the methods of interest. I have searched all over looking for possible example code that i can work from. When my search failed I decided to post my question here.

Answer (score 1):

The list `pe.sections` contains a section object for each PE section. Iterate over that and use the methods `get_hash_md5()` and `get_hash_sha256()`. Example:

```
import pefile
pe = pefile.PE('/path/to/file')
for sect in pe.sections:
    print sect.Name
    print sect.get_hash_md5()
    print sect.get_hash_sha256()
    print
```